# Join query equivalent to Not IN clause (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query with a `not in` clause like this:

```
select * 
FROM COMPANY c 
where c.company_id not In (SELECT SenderId 
                            FROM CrossRef) 
  and c.id not in (select company_id 
                    FROM USER)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to re-write that query using a left join in SQL Server 2008.

I tried the following one but it's not giving the correct result

```
select c.id, c.company_id 
from COMPANY c 
left join CrossRef cr on c.company_id != cr.senderid, COMPANY c1 
left join USER u on c1.id != u.company_id
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Company C
LEFT JOIN CrossRef R ON R.SenderID = C.CompanyID
LEFT JOIN [User] U ON U.company_id = C.id
WHERE R.SenderID IS NULL
  AND U.company_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks its working.I didnt understand why User is enclosed in [] and the where clause. Am fairly new to sql server08, could you please explain

Comment: @RanPaul: `User` is a reserved keyword in T-SQL - therefore, if you name a table `User`, you must refer to it using square brackets. Same applies to e.g.  `Order` and others - [here's the complete list of reserved keywords in SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx).

Comment: Thanks and cant we use "!=" like LEFT JOIN CrossRef R ON R.SenderID != C.CompanyID and why the where clause checking for senderid,companyid IS NULL?

Comment: The != operator would result in a cartesian product. Every row in the source table would be matched against every row that did not match up on the second table. Therefore you would get a row from the source table for each record in the second table, and vice versa. In this case the left join matches the datasets together, then eliminates the rows that have a record. This is checked in the where clause as that occurs after the rows have been joined.